# Validate example part of swagger specification against its schema

Tags: validation, swagger, schema, openapi

Is it possible to validate `example` part of swagger document against corresponding schema?

I've found tools for both validating schema itself (like http://editor.swagger.io or [swagger-cli](https://github.com/APIDevTools/swagger-cli) etc - but that's just linting) and validating requests/responses against schema (things like [swagger-express-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-express-middleware) or [swagger-assertions](https://github.com/Maks3w/SwaggerAssertions)).

But I'd like to validate that `example`s in `responses` and `definitions` are consistent with schemas.
For example:

```
swagger: '2.0'
paths:
  /test:
    get:
      description: test endpoint
      produces:
        - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              name:
                type: string
              id:
                type: integer
            example:
              name: 13
              id: some string
```

seems to be "correct" for all those tools even if `example` contains incorrect structure.

is there a tool that can do that?